# Python newbie here >Implement a Search Algorithm<

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask

I am expanding my knowledge with Python and I hope anyone can help me with my assignment below.

Search specification:

1. All of the search parameters are optional. That means a user can pass no search parameter and the function should return all users. The user can also pass just the id as a parameter and it should just return the user with that id. The user can also pass multiple parameters and the function should return all the users that match ANY of the parameters provided.
2. The id is unique. If the id is included in the search parameters, then immediately include the user with the passed id.
3. The name can be partially matched and is case insensitive. That means that if we have users with names John Smith, Janice Smith, and Mary Smith, passing the word "Smith" to the name parameter should include all of them in the results. 4.The age parameter should include users that are in the range of age - 1 to age + 1. This means that if we pass 26 to the age parameter, we should include users with ages 25 to 27. –
4. The occupation parameter can be partially matched and is case insensitive. This means that if we pass "er" to the occupation parameter, we should include all users with an occupation that contains "er" in the results. Do not include a user in the results more than once.

The search endpoint is: http://127.0.0.1:5000/search. The user can pass the following query parameters:
id
name
age
occupation

**Here's the search_data.py**

> ```
> USERS = [
>     {"id": "1", "name": "Janice, "age": 18, "occupation": "Developer"},
>     {"id": "2", "name": "Mary Jane", "age": 32, "occupation": "Wifer"},
>     {"id": "3", "name": "Mary Ann", "age": 15, "occupation": "Student"},
>     {"id": "4", "name": "John Smith", "age": 21, "occupation": "Architect"},
>     {"id": "5", "name": "Janice Smith", "age": 41, "occupation": "CEO"},
>     {"id": "6", "name": "Mary Smith", "age": 44, "occupation": "Manager"},
> ]
> ```

**Example request calls to the search endpoint are:**

http://127.0.0.1:5000/search?id=1

> `Result:  [ {"id": "1", "name": "Janice, "age": 18, "occupation": "Student"} ]`
>
> http://127.0.0.1:5000/search?id=2&name=Mary
>
> ```
> [
>   {"id": "2", "name": "Mary Jane", "age": 32, "occupation": "House Wife"},
>   {"id": "3", "name": "Mary Ann", "age": 15, "occupation": "Student"},
>   {"id": "6", "name": "Mary Smith", "age": 44, "occupation": "Manager"}
> ]
> ```
>
> **Existing search.py code:**
>
> ```
> from flask import Blueprint, request, jsonify
> from .data.search_data import USERS
>
> bp = Blueprint("search", __name__, url_prefix="/search")
>
> @bp.route("")
> def search():
> query_params = request.args.to_dict()
> results = search_users(query_params)
> return jsonify(results), 200
>
> def search_users(query_params):
>     """Search users database
>
> Parameters:
> query_params: a dictionary containing the following search parameters:
> id: string
> name: string
> age: string
> occupation: string
>
>
> Returns:
> a list of users that match the search parameters
>     """
>
> # Start with all users
> filtered_users = USERS
>
> # Filter by ID if provided
> if 'id' in query_params:
> user_id = query_params['id']
> filtered_users = [user for user in filtered_users if user['id'] == user_id]
>
> # Filter by name if provided (case-insensitive partial match)
> if 'name' in query_params:
> name = query_params['name'].lower()
> filtered_users = [user for user in filtered_users if name in user['name'].lower()]
>
> # Filter by age if provided (within age - 1 to age + 1 range)
> if 'age' in query_params:
> try:
> age = int(query_params['age'])
> filtered_users = [user for user in filtered_users if age - 1 <= user['age'] <= age + 1]
> except ValueError:
> pass  # Handle invalid age parameter gracefully
>
> # Filter by occupation if provided (case-insensitive partial match)
> if 'occupation' in query_params:
> occupation = query_params['occupation'].lower()
> filtered_users = [user for user in filtered_users if occupation in user['occupation'].lower()]
>
> # Remove duplicates
> filtered_users = [dict(t) for t in {tuple(d.items()) for d in filtered_users}]
>
> return filtered_users
> ```

I've tried modification of my search.py code and still showing empty results when trying to request multiple parameters like this:

http://127.0.0.1:5000/search?id=5&name=Janice&age=32&occupation=Dev

Result should show:

```
{"id": "5", "name": "Janice Smith", "age": 41, "occupation": "CEO"},
{"id": "1", "name": "Janice, "age": 18, "occupation": "Developer"},
```

For example:

For this request endpoint: http://127.0.0.1:5000/search?id=5&name=Janice&age=32&occupation=Dev

It will show all the line that has an ID == 5 | partial name == Janice | age == 32 (+1 or -1) | partial Occupation == Dev.

-First result should shows first ID == 5:

```
{"id": "5", "name": "Janice Smith", "age": 41, "occupation": "CEO"},
```

-Then second result should show all partial named == Janice

```
{"id": "1", "name": "Janice, "age": 18, "occupation": "Developer"},
```

-Then 3rd result should show all age between 31 & 33 (since its -1 or +1)

```
{"id": "2", "name": "Mary Jane", "age": 32, "occupation": "Wifer"},
```

-Then lastly, it should show all partial occupation that starts with Dev

```
{"id": "1", "name": "Janice, "age": 18, "occupation": "Developer"},
```

> > so the final results should be

```
{"id": "5", "name": "Janice Smith", "age": 41, "occupation": "CEO"},
{"id": "1", "name": "Janice, "age": 18, "occupation": "Developer"},
{"id": "2", "name": "Mary Jane", "age": 32, "occupation": "Wifer"},
```

Comment: hi Chiko! Can you explain how/why the example requests would produce the desired results above?

Comment: Hello Mark, thank you for responding to me post.
Search specification of the task:

1. All of the search parameters are optional. That means a user can pass no search parameter and the function should return all users. The user can also pass just the id as a parameter and it should just return the user with that id. The user can also pass multiple parameters and the function should return all the users that match ANY of the parameters provided.
2. The id is unique. If the id is included in the search parameters, then immediately include the user with the passed id.

Comment: 3. The name can be partially matched and is case insensitive. That means that if we have users with names John Smith, Janice Smith, and Mary Smith, passing the word "Smith" to the name parameter should include all of them in the results.
4.The age parameter should include users that are in the range of age - 1 to age + 1. This means that if we pass 26 to the age parameter, we should include users with ages 25 to 27.

Comment: 4. The occupation parameter can be partially matched and is case insensitive. This means that if we pass "er" to the occupation parameter, we should include all users with an occupation that contains "er" in the results.
Do not include a user in the results more than once.

Comment: For this example here: http://127.0.0.1:5000/search?id=5&name=Janice&age=32&occupation=Dev

It queries the ID:5 & name: Janice & age = 32 and occupation = Dev

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I understood that, I just wasn't sure why you'd get `{"id": "5", "name": "Janice Smith", "age": 41, "occupation": "CEO"},
{"id": "1", "name": "Janice, "age": 18, "occupation": "Developer"},`. If you could spell out to me why those two rows are picked that would be great! Because they seem very different to the queries

Comment: http://127.0.0.1:5000/search?id=5&name=Janice&age=32&occupation=Dev

Comment: It will show all the line that has an ID == 5 | partial name == Janice | age == 32 (+1 or -1) | partial Occupation == Dev.

Comment: results should shows first ID == 5:
{"id": "5", "name": "Janice Smith", "age": 41, "occupation": "CEO"},
Then second result should show all partial named == Janice 
{"id": "1", "name": "Janice, "age": 18, "occupation": "Developer"},
Then 3rd result should show all age between 31 & 33 (since its -1 or +1)
{"id": "2", "name": "Mary Jane", "age": 32, "occupation": "Wifer"},
Then lastly, it should show all partial occupationthat starts with Dev
{"id": "1", "name": "Janice, "age": 18, "occupation": "Developer"},

Comment: so the final results should be 

{"id": "5", "name": "Janice Smith", "age": 41, "occupation": "CEO"},
{"id": "1", "name": "Janice, "age": 18, "occupation": "Developer"},
{"id": "2", "name": "Mary Jane", "age": 32, "occupation": "Wifer"},

Comment: I hope this explain well. It's my first time posting this question and I wish I can provide you as detailed as I can.

Comment: Thank you for checking this again for me @Mark. I have edited the definition above so it will give all readers more understanding about my question :)